# Experience Builder: Custom Self Register Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud, self-registration

When a guest user tries to register for the `community` with an existing email address, he gets following error.
`Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted.`

[image]

I wanted this error to be customized to a meaningful error like `Username already exists`. But unfortunately, I couldn't find any source or tip to change the error message. Then I created a custom `lightning-web-component` with custom `Apex Controller`. Now, when an user registers, I want to create an user that is linked to the `Account` which is configured at the community's `login & registration` section.

How do you get the configured `accountId` and `profileId` in apex controller or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Account Id` and `Profile Id` are not required to be specified when creating a community user via a custom `selfRegisterController`

```
User u = new User();
u.FirstName = 'FisrtName';
u.LastName = 'LastName';
...
// no need to specify profileId
...
```

```
Site.createExternalUser(u, NULL); // pass null for account Id
```

Then salesforce will automatically identify relevant `Account Id` and `Profile Id` as long as you have configured it in `community settings`.